# CentOS 6.4 lock-up ...no explanation

Tags: centos, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a CentOS 6.4 server on an oldish box (HP ProLiant ML350 G4) that I've recently installed on and it's been up less than 24 hours. It has 6 146 GB 10k SCSI drives in RAID 1+0 that are also brand new and no signs of drive failure or any type of hardware notices. Yet, randomly this will happen:

[image]

Once this occurs, I can't log in (this occurs at the login prompt) and SSH is not responding. Ping is responding, but otherwise the box is locked up tight. Note that a reboot solves the issue for a brief time, but this has occured at least 3 different times on CentOS 6.4 *and* Debian 6, both clean installs.

Anyone have any insight?

Edit: Logs after the fact show nothing (not even the messages mentioned).

Comment: What controller do you have in the machine? SmartArray 6400-series? SmartArray 641? Have you updated firmware?

Comment: SmartArray 641. I just flashed the firmware (it had 2.2 and the latest was 2.8.4). So we'll see what happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firmware on HP gear is always important. The Smart Array 6400 and 641/642 controllers of that era (2003-2005) used to freeze and do all sorts of funky things in certain situations. Update the firmware to the most recent.

On the Linux side, the [CCISS block device driver](http://cciss.sourceforge.net) has been in the kernel for ages. It's typically stable. But there are some other considerations on EL6. Adjust your I/O scheduler or use the `tuned-adm` utility. Make sure you have a battery-backed cache on that controller if you're doing any write-heavy activity. And run a health status check on the controller with the `hpacucli ctrl all show config detail` command. Just make sure there aren't any disks in a funky or prefailure state.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted while I monitor the server to make sure it behaves itself.